# Create a folder via SSH in python

Tags: python, ssh

I want to create a folder in which I can add a subfolder with the current date and a progressive number and move there a file in which I'm interested.
After the connection to the ssh server is made, I send this code:

```
from datetime import datetime
i=0
now=datetime.now()
var_log='/var/log/gwlog_0_debug'
folder_Salvo='mkdir /Salvo/'+now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')+'/'+str(i)
print (folder_Salvo)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(folder_Salvo)
path_Salvo=' /Salvo/'+now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')+'/'+str(i) 
log_Salvo= path_Salvo+'/gwlog_0_debug'
command='cp '+ var_log + log_Salvo
print (command)
ssh_stdin, ssh_stdout, ssh_stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
```

the output of the print commands seems correct

```
mkdir /Salvo/07-05-2022/0
cp /var/log/gwlog_0_debug /Salvo/07-05-2022/0/gwlog_0_debug
```

but the folder is not created. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any relevant content in the `ssh_stderr` variable?

Comment: nope I don't use them in the software, actually they can be removed.

Comment: Does the `/Salvo`  directory exist on the target machine? Based on your code, without any configuration on my target machine I get this error (`print(ssh_stderr.readlines())`): `Cannot create directory “/Salvo/07-05-2022/0”: No such file or folder`

Comment: well no I'm expecting that using the mkdir it should create it...am I wrong?

Comment: By default `mkdir` can create only one directory at a time. You need to use the `-p` flag to create a directory and its parents in case they do not exist: `folder_Salvo='mkdir -p /Salvo/'+now.strftime('%m-%d-%Y')+'/'+str(i)`

Comment: ahm!!!indead I've found a made-in-house solution in which basically I repeated the mkdir per each folder I wanted to create. I wasn't aware about the -p flag!thanks for the hint!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246174/discussion-between-martinmistere-and-martin-tovmassian).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done like this:

```
folder="C:\try\attempts"
os.makedirs(folder)
```